# How to feed data into ode while doing optimisation

Tags: r, optimization, ode

I'm new to R. I found very useful code, which I've tried to use for my            purposes. however, I get an error:

> Error in func(time, state, parms, ...) : object 'k4' not found and Error in func(time, state, parms, ...) : object 'E' not found

I don't know where the problem is as I can see all parameters and data.frame is correct as well.

Thank you everyone for taking time to look at this. I've tried to reduce the number of parameters to3 (k10, k11,k12), and using estimated values for the remaining (embeded values in the code). However, I still get an error message, the E value from data.frame is not passed into rxnrate function and as result ode can't use it. I've tried to use events and forcing functions but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you for spotting P4, it was a typo, should be P, I've corrected already.

Editors note: This was crossposted to Rhelp and that message included the source of this code as a stackoverflow question "r-parameter and initial conditions fitting ODE models with nls.lm."

```
         #set working directory
         setwd("~/R/wkspace")
         #load libraries
          library(ggplot2)
         library(reshape2)
         library(deSolve)
         library(minpack.lm)
         time=c(22,23,24,46,47,48)
         cE=c(15.92,24.01,25.29,15.92,24.01,25.29)
         cP=c(0.3,0.14,0.29,0.3,0.14,0.29)
         cL=c(6.13,3.91,38.4,6.13,3.91,38.4)
         df<-data.frame(time,cE,cP,cL)
         df
         names(df)=c("time","cE","cP","cL")

         #rate function
         rxnrate=function(t,c,parms){

            #rate constant passed through a list called
         k1=parms$k1
         k2=parms$k2
         k3=parms$k3
         k4=parms$k4
          k5=parms$k5
         k6=parms$k6
         k7=parms$k7
         k8=parms$k8
         k9=parms$k9
         k10=parms$k10
         #c is the concentration of species
         #derivatives dc/dt are computed below
         r=rep(0,length(c))
         r[1]=(k1+(k2*E^k10)/(k3^k10+E^k10))/(1+P/k6)-k4*         ((1+k5*P)/(1+k7*E))*c["pLH"]; #dRP_LH/dt
         r[2]=(1/k8)*k4*((1+k5*P)/(1+k7*E))*c["p"]-k9*c["L"] #dL/dt
         return(list(r))
          }


ssq=function(myparms){
     #initial concentration
     cinit=c(pLH=unname(myparms[11]),LH=unname(myparms[12]))
     print(cinit)
     #time points for which conc is reported
     #include the points where data is available
     t=c(seq(0,46,2),df$time)
     t=sort(unique(t))
    #parameters from the parameters estimation
    k1=myparms[1]
    k2=myparms[2]
    k3=myparms[3]
    k4=myparms[4]
     k5=myparms[5]
     k6=myparms[6]
     k7=myparms[7]
    k8=myparms[8]
    k9=myparms[9]
    k10=myparms[10]
#solve ODE for a given set of parameters
  out=ode(y=cinit,times=t,func=rxnrate,parms=list(k1=k1,k2=k2,k3=k3,k4=k4,k5=k5,k6=k6,k7=k7,k8=k8,k9=k9,k10=k10,E=cE,P=cP))

    #Filter data that contains time points
     outdf=data.frame(out)
     outdf=outdf[outdf$time%in% df$time,]
    #Evaluate predicted vs experimental residual
     preddf=melt(outdf,id.var="time",variable.name="species",value.name="conc")
     expdf=melt(df,id.var="time",variable.name="species",value.name="conc")
     ssqres=preddf$conc-expdf$conc
    return(ssqres)
}
# parameter fitting using levenberg marquart
#initial guess for parameters
myparms=c(k1=500, k2=4500, k3=200,k4=2.42, k5=0.26,k6=12.2,k7=0.004,k8=55,k9=24,k10=8,pLH=14.5,LH=3.55)


#fitting
fitval=nls.lm(par=myparms,fn=ssq)
#summary of fit
summary(fitval)
#estimated parameter
parest=as.list(coef(fitval))
```

Comment: This is **not** good code. By all means use it if it works, but do not think that it's terrible style of breaking out a list or vector one item at a time is anything other than bad practice.

Comment: The error I get is `Error in func(time, state, parms, ...) : object 'P4' not found`, and I don't see any definition of P4 anywhere. If I replace that with `P[4] the `nls.lm` call runs without error although many warnings and the output doesn't look promising.

Comment: It's also a bit optimistic (perhaps even foolhardy) to attempt estimation of 12 parameters in a non-linear model with only 6 data points.

Comment: @42- : isn't "impossible" closer to the mark?  To the OP: even if you were to solve the superficial problems to get the code working, this simply won't work.  Barring some special-case advanced techniques for collapsing redundant parameters, you simply can't fit more parameters than you have data points (even fitting nearly as many parameters as data points is difficult and inadvisable).

Comment: @BenBolker I was hoping to leave open the possibility that there were more data points. It does make me wonder whether there ought to be at least a warning generated when the number of parameters to be estimated exceeds the number of data points.

Comment: Hello, Thank you, everyone, for taking a time to look at this code. I presume that I can reduce the number of parameters to 3 (leaving k10, and initial values k11 and k12 as parameters), I have approximations for the remaining parameters.